# Flopping top set on an all club flop

Tags: cash-game

OK so I'm on a $2/$5 table, sitting on a stack over $1000. I have 8⋄8♠ in the SB.

Preflop:

- Hijack makes it $20
- I flat
- The BB, a tight aggressive player with a bigger stack than mine, makes it $75.
- Hijack folds
- I call

Flop: 8♣5♣4♣

How do you play this ? Thank you.

---

Hover over the area below to see what happened:

> What actually happened is I bet 100$ and he tanked and folded.

Comment: I changed your hand from 8d 8c to 8d 8s because you said the the 8c actually came on the flop. Please edit this if it's wrong.

Comment: I agree all sounds great thank you. And yes this is live game. At the playground poker club in Montreal. Come on down

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The most important thing to note here is that it's very unlikely for him to have a hand better than yours. If you consider the entirety of his range, only a small portion of it are suited club hands. As such, the likelihood of him having a completed flush here is minimal. It's important to note that against a completed flush, **you still have 34.49% equity with your set.** Against a completed straight (very very unlikely for him to have this), 76s, you still have 37.12% equity. This is excellent. Against the best hands in his range, you are still doing well with your full house draw.

His range, due to the reraise preflop, is likely more weighted to premiums: overpairs, very strong Ax, KQs (maybe), and, depending on the level of aggression and stack sizes at the table, suited connectors {JTs-54s} (not very likely). As such, you should be fairly confident that you currently have the best hand.

Now's the time to extract value while protecting your hand from the multitude of one-card flush draws in his range. The pot is currently $172. So, after the big blind checks to you, you'll want to bet 70-85% of the pot. How much exactly is really dependent on how much attention your opponents are paying to pot and bet sizes. If this is live casino $2/$5, that likely means not that much attention.

So betting somewhere around $120-$150 will be best. You charge any one-card flush draws while getting value from overpairs. If he check-raises all-in, I'd be inclined to call readless since you have so much equity versus his range.

So, well played. I'd bet more on the flop than you did but your line was good.